# How to UPDATE MySQL Database if I have different ids?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem when trying to UPDATE MySQL database. I'll write the code below.

The problem is that, I have some reviews/feedbacks from my application, and I'm trying to edit a comment from one of them. I'll put the code here:

***HTML CODE***

```
<input type="text" size="70" 
id="edit<?php echo $row['id'];?>" 
name="edit" 
style="display: none;">

<input type="image" 
name="save" 
id="save<?php echo $row['id'];?>" 
value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" 
onclick="ask_confirm('Are you sure you want to edit the comment?','save<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')" style="display: none;" src="png/accept.png" />
```

***PHP CODE***

```
if(isset($_POST['save']) && isset($_POST['edit'])){
    $edit = $_POST['edit'];
    foreach($_POST['save'] as $here)
         mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE feedback_rate SET comment = ".$edit." WHERE id = $here");
}
```

And when I ***print_r($_POST)***, it shows me this:

```
Array (
    [edit] => 
    [save_x] => 8
    [save_y] => 9
    [save] => 48
)
```

It doesn't take the [edit] POST. Any help would be great! Thanks guys!

Comment: As Hoijof said ... What kind of value you want to get when your input field has no value attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input edit doesn't have a value. You should put a value to the value property in order to get anything in the POST, like this:

```
<input type="text" size="70" 
    value="edit<?php echo $row['id'];?>" 
    name="edit" 
    style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes agree with Hoijof. Set a value so that it can be carried over to the next page.
That would probably solve the problem.